# Minimize downtime (Azure Website + SQL DB)

Tags: azure, redundancy

My Azure websites are down a lot, four outages (30 minutes - 3 hours) in the past 30 days. I only use one small standard website and one web SQL DB in US West so I can't expect 99.5%. This week (a few days ago and currently), 503 errors were / are the problem, but I also experienced substantial DB downtimes at other occasions.

My question is: what can I do (with hopefully not too much additional costs and effort) to raise stability? Which measures did other Azure users try? Would this have prevented the 3 hour downtime last Monday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) three things you can do:

1. Scale your website so that you have 2 instances running ([How to Scale Websites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-scale));
2. Deploy a another copy of the website in a different region, and use traffic manager to Load Balance them ([Traffic Manager Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/))
3. Create another instance of the database, and sync them ([Getting Started with Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync))

Comment: Good summary, thanks. Do you know if this will about double my costs or will I get away with less?

Comment: I'd like to provide an answer, but the pricing website doesn't really make it very clear as to the additional cost for additional instances.  I'm having a look at my setup to see if I can work it out.  Obviously running a deployment in a different region would double the cost.

Comment: @sabbour Care to elaborate?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Websites give you a 99.9% uptime guarantee, regardless of the number of instances deployed. So simply scaling beyond 1 instance wouldn't improve availability (or avoid that downtime). What could benefit them is deploying in another datacenter and setting up Traffic Manager as you suggested.

Comment: @BrendanGreen point 1 gives you better throughput as now you will have more than one instance serving your site

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that with Websites, you get a 99.9% availability for websites running is Basic and Standard mode **regardless of the number of instances deployed**. You can view the SLA document here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=301329&clcid=0x409

Regarding the 503 errors you experiences, this was an intermittent issue http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#history